# How to darken the reorder control in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a pale green coloured tableview and when I enter Edit mode the reorder controls on the right edge are almost invisible. Can anyone tell me how to either use my own image for this or darken the system image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I don't want anyone else wasting time on this. You can't change this... I have resorted to switching my TableView's background colour back to white when I enter editing mode. This is yet one more horrible compromise but c'est la vie! Same with the right chevron in the accessoryView. It would seem obvious that one might be able to set this to the colour of their choice. Not so. The only way I found for doing this, simply darkening the chevron, was to subclass a UIControl and write my own drawRect method. Apple has an awful load of money yet cannot appear to employ enough programmers to keep a handle on this sort of very, very simple UI stuff. It appears that the bigger the libraries get the less we are able to actually do with them.